# Skipped 844 frames! Too much work in MainThread caused by simple AlertDialog with Spinners

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I use a AlertDialog with two spinners, the App itself is pretty fast, but when I start this Dialog the application slows down when the dialog is finished the speed rises.

One of the Spinners is really "heavy" it contains 60 elements consisting of one picture and one TextView. Picture (ImageView) is small, but the original picture is 512x512 PNG 12,54kB (is this to large?).

One ArralyList (for the small spinner) is initialized directly, the small one is initialized at start of the application.

## This is the AlertDialog

```java
public class dialog_CardWithdrawRequest extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private static final String TAG = "dialog_CardWithdrawRequ";

private ArrayList<obj_PrintState> printStatesList;
private Spinner sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Printer;

private Spinner sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Country;
private sendChoosenCountryAndPrintState listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    
    try {
        listener = (dialog_CardWithdrawRequest.sendChoosenCountryAndPrintState) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
                " must implement sendChoosenCountryAndPrintState listener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initArrays();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_cardwithdrawrequest, null);
    
    final int Driver;
    final int iCurrentDriverPosition;
    Bundle receivingBundle = this.getArguments();
    if(receivingBundle != null){
        Driver = receivingBundle.getInt("Driver");
        iCurrentDriverPosition = receivingBundle.getInt("CurrentCountryPosition");
    }else{
        Driver = INT_DEFAULT_VALUE;
        iCurrentDriverPosition =0;
    }
    
    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_CardWithdrawRequest_Title);
    
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancle, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        
        }
    });
    
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            obj_Country selectedCountry = (obj_Country) sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Country.getSelectedItem();
            String sSelectedCountry = selectedCountry.getsHexCountryCode();
            
            obj_PrintState selectedPrintState = (obj_PrintState) sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Printer.getSelectedItem();
            String sSelectedPrintRequest = selectedPrintState.getsPrinterRequestHex();
            
            listener.choosenCountryAndPrintState(sSelectedCountry, sSelectedPrintRequest, Driver);
            
        }
    });
    sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Country = view.findViewById(R.id.sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Country);
    sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Printer = view.findViewById(R.id.sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Printer);
    
    adapter_Spinner_Country adapterCountry = new adapter_Spinner_Country(getContext(), objCountryList);
    adapter_Spinner_Printer adapterPrinter = new adapter_Spinner_Printer(getContext(), printStatesList);
    
    sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Country.setAdapter(adapterCountry);
    sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Printer.setAdapter(adapterPrinter);
    
    sp_DialogCardWithdrawRequest_Country.setSelection(iCurrentDriverPosition);
    return builder.create();
}

    private void initArrays(){
        printStatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        printStatesList.add(new obj_PrintState(PRINTREQUEST_NONE, getText(R.string.dialog_CardWithdrawRequest_PrintRequest_None).toString()));
        printStatesList.add(new obj_PrintState(PRINTREQUEST_UTC, getText(R.string.dialog_CardWithdrawRequest_PrintRequest_UTC).toString()));
        printStatesList.add(new obj_PrintState(PRINTREQUEST_LOCAL, getText(R.string.dialog_CardWithdrawRequest_PrintRequest_Local).toString()));
    }
    
public interface sendChoosenCountryAndPrintState{
    void choosenCountryAndPrintState(String sSelectedCountry, String sSelectedPrintRequest, int Driver);
}

}
```

## This is the call from mainActivity

```java
helperThread = new HandlerThread("HelperThread");
    helperThread.start();
    Handler helperHandler = new Handler(helperThread.getLooper());
    
   helperHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog_CardWithdrawRequest dialog_cardWithdrawRequest = new dialog_CardWithdrawRequest();
            Bundle information = new Bundle();
            information.putInt("Driver", iDriver);
            information.putInt("CurrentCountryPosition", finalIPosition);
            dialog_cardWithdrawRequest.setArguments(information);
            dialog_cardWithdrawRequest.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"CardWithdrawRequest");
        }
   });
```

As you can See, I already tried to post this "hard work" on a different thread, but I think an `AlertDialog` always runs in UI thread, I don't know.

I also tried to use:

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you think 0.1MB is small enought?

Comment: You should try and feel if it's small enough for you. 10 times faster is a good starting point, IMO.

Comment: If you make an answer out of your comment I will accept it. But please also show how did you know the needed memory space for the pictures and how a spinner saves it's elements. This would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`... 512x512 PNG 12,54kB (is this to large?)` ... Yes, it is.

Considering that the decompressed raw bitmap is x * y * 4 bytes (R, G, B and A components, each weighting 1 full byte).
Therefore, each image of yours weights 1 MB in memory.

By the way, there's no need to use an ImageView: just set the image as a compound drawable in your TextView and squeeze out some performance.

Here is an interesting link:
https://antonioleiva.com/textview_power_drawables/